# Ubuntu 16.04 pulseaudio no HDMI sink

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I have installed ubuntu server 16.04 on Intel NUC. I have manually installed pulseaudio. Audio output unfortunately only works for Analog output and not HDMI:

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC283 Analog [ALC283 Analog]
  Subdevicealex@gigabyte:~$s: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

but pacmd lists only one sink.

```
$ pacmd list-sinks
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
        name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
        state: SUSPENDED
        suspend cause: IDLE
        priority: 9959
        volume: front-left: 30129 /  46% / -20.25 dB,   front-right: 30129 /  46% / -20.25 dB
                balance 0.00
        base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
        volume steps: 65537
        muted: no
        current latency: 0.00 ms
        max request: 0 KiB
        max rewind: 0 KiB
        monitor source: 0
        sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
        channel map: front-left,front-right
                     Stereo
        used by: 0
        linked by: 0
        configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 371.52 ms
        card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
        module: 6
        properties:
                alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
                device.api = "alsa"
                device.class = "sound"
                alsa.class = "generic"
                alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
                alsa.name = "ALC283 Analog"
                alsa.id = "ALC283 Analog"
                alsa.subdevice = "0"
                alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
                alsa.device = "0"
                alsa.card = "0"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xd0810000 irq 92"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "8086"
                device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
                device.product.id = "0f04"
                device.product.name = "Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller"
                device.form_factor = "internal"
                device.string = "front:0"
                device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
                device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
                device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
                device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
                device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
                device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
                alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC283"
                alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0283,1458fa53,00100003 HDA:80862882,80860101,00100000"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        ports:
                analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 user, : yes)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
        active port: <analog-output-headphones>
```

Manually playing sounds with

`aplay -D hw:0,3 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav`
or
`speaker-test -c 2 -r 48000 -D hw:0,3` 
does not deliver any sound over HDMI.

Any idea what I could try to get HDMI sound working?

Comment: I never had to manually install pulseaudio. Why did you do that?

Comment: Check available card profiles with `pacmd list-cards`. You probably need to switch to another profile to get the sink available.